# Django Form Is Valid not producing any errors but returning False

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to update an existing model row (add choices to an existing ManyToMany field with previous entries) with a form but when I use the is_valid() it returns false, I have checked for errors in a few ways but no errors are being displayed
I have used in my template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="errorlogin">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="errorlogin">
        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and, in my views, after the is_valid and before the is_valid function is called:

```
print(form.errors)
```

My code is below:
views.py

```
def lessonRecord(request,id):
if request.method == "POST":
    id = Lessons.objects.get(id=id)
    form = forms.LessonAddForm(request.POST,instance=id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('lessons:lessonsView')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    id = Lessons.objects.get(id=id)
    form = forms.LessonAddForm(instance=id , user=request.user)
return render(request,'lessons/lesson_record.html',{'id':id,'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class LessonAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, user,*args, **kwargs):
    super(LessonAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(
        Q(username=user) |
        Q(customuser__username=user)
    )
class Meta:
    model = models.Lessons
    fields = ['attendees']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lied in the views and the forms. I wasn't passing the user through on a post request

```
def lessonRecord(request,id):
if request.method == "POST":
    id = Lessons.objects.get(id=id)
    form = forms.LessonAddForm(request.POST,user=request.user,instance=id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('lessons:lessonsView')
```

forms.py

```
class LessonAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(LessonAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['attendees'].queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(
        Q(username=user) |
        Q(customuser__username=user)
    )
```